# ARToolkit Mobile Library Tutorials/Demos

Tags: ipad, augmented-reality

Does anyone know of any good tutorials or demos for the ARToolkit Mobile Library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

with the ARToolkit Mobile come four well documented examples for using OpenGL, Wavefront, OSG and Video formats.

Other options are the support [wiki](http://www.artoolworks.com/support/library/Main_Page) of ARToolworks or the support [forum](http://www.artoolworks.com/community/forum/).

Cheers,

Mark

Comment: Thanks!I guess I will just wait for my license agreement to go through.